# Difference between List<string> lst = new List() and List<> lst = new List()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to know the difference between `List<string> lst = new List()`  and `List<> lst = new List()`

Comment: The latter doesn't compile?

Comment: Here's the MSDN link to List<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: I strongly recommend reading Jeffrey Richter - CLR via C# =) To make it easy to understand. Especially chapters 11-13, but better whole book.

Comment: Apparently you have not experimented with the two options to try to determine the difference on your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `List` type. `List<T>` (or `List(Of T)` in VB) is a generic. It means that the list can only hold a type you pass in.

For instance:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("hello"); // OK
list1.Add(123); // Compiler error

List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list2.Add("hello"); // Compiler error
list2.Add(123); // OK
```

You can read more about the [generic list at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

If you want an un-typed list, you can use an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add("hello"); // OK
list.Add(123); // OK
```

But then you must know the type when you use an item from the list, since it can be any object.